# Can you have a text variable shown within a text node?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to a text node, where to states the user's name they chose at the start through a textbox to be displayed within a text node and wondering if it is possible. This is what I've done so far and it isn't working. Also, a unique piece of dialogue comes up if named Andrew.

```js
      //if statement to determine the users name and save it
      if (nextTextNodeId == 60) {
      var InputName = document.getElementById('name').value
      name = InputName
      setState: { InputName: name }
      if (name == "Andrew") {
          ToggleInputOff()
          state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
          showTextNode(4)
          return;
      }
      else if (name == "") {
          state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
          showTextNode(3)
          return; 
      }
      else {
          ToggleInputOff()
          state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
          showTextNode(5)
          return;
      }
      return ToggleInputOff()
      }

      //Example
        {
            id: 5,
            text: "Welcome " + name + " let us start the day!",
            options: [
                {
                    text: "Let's go",
                    nextText: 6
                }

            ]
        },
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're missing the commas to separate your vars unless things like `name`, `state` and `nextTextNodeId` are declared elsewhere already within scope. So it looks like your example may be incomplete. Then it's just a matter of plopping that string in a text node which is easy enough but are you asking how to set like `innerText` in an existing element? Or how to dynamically create an element and add it? Your question and example make it a bit unclear.

Comment: Apologies, first time StackOverflow-er here. The code I copied in was just parts of it, I think I'm fine in that regard it's just I don't know how to put a pre-existing name variable that is created, into a text node text: if that makes any sense.

Comment: No worries, so are you wanting to place that value from your example object like `document.getElementById(<someElementId>).innerText = yourObjectName.text`? Or are you asking how to create the object you have your in your example? Orrrr....? ;)